# gnome-terminal run roslaunch after ssh without closing the terminal

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I 'd like to write a file.sh as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "roslaunch abc slam.launch"
sleep 2s
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ssh ubuntu@ipaddress; sleep 4s; roslaunch bringup minimal.launch"
sleep 2s
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.108 "roslaunch lidar scan.launch"'
```

It runs smoothly for the 1st roslaunch, the second command just ended at login in result of ssh, the last command , it open and  then closed. I tried to change some script inside, and result shown "bash: roslaunch command not found"

How should i do ? thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380084/gnome-terminal-run-roslaunch-after-ssh-without-closing-the-terminal/) by [Ksan](https://answers.ros.org/users/75902/ksan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you trying to accomplish here? It looks like you want `roslaunch` to ssh into a machine and launch the launch file on that machine, but I'm not entirely sure. If this is the case, this functionality is already built in to `roslaunch` using the [machine tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2021-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ksan](https://answers.ros.org/users/75902/ksan/) on 2021-06-12**:
I want to write a script to use ssh login into a computer and then run roslaunch there.
I already setup ssh login without password